# Django: Getting "ManyToManyField cannot define a relation with abstract class" error

Tags: django-models

I need this inheritance:

Item(models.Model)
...
class Meta:
        abstract = True

Food(Item)
...

Meal(Item)
items= models.ManyToManyField(Item,related_name='meal_items')

But I am getting this error:
AssertionError: ManyToManyField cannot define a relation with abstract class Item

What should I do? Any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multi-table inheritance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)? ManyToMany fields have to link actual database tables.